# javascript: построить ассоциативный массив на данных из обычного массива

Tags: javascript, массивы, map-reduce

есть массив структур данных

```
data = [
    {key: 'xxx', value: 123, other: X},
    {key: 'yyy', value: 456, other: Y},
    {key: 'zzz', value: 789, other: Z},
];
```

как создать из него ассоциативный массив:

```
{
    'xxx': 123,
    'yyy': 456,
    'zzz': 789
}
```

Я делаю с помощью метода `reduce`:

```
output = data.reduce((res, elem) => {
    res[elem.key] = elem.value;
    return res;
}, {});
```

Но можно ли это сделать в 1 строчку без вложенной функции, например с помощью того же `map`?

Comment: запишите то же самое покороче `data.reduce((res, elem) => ((res[elem.key] = elem.value),res), {})`

Comment: Можно же и ваш код написать в одну строку. У каждого своя длина строки в линтере) А можно функцию сделать и положить в прототип и всё)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) в помощь

```js
const data = [
    {key: 'xxx', value: 123, other: 1},
    {key: 'yyy', value: 456, other: 2},
    {key: 'zzz', value: 789, other: 3},
];

let output = Object.fromEntries(data.map(v => [v.key, v.value]));

console.log(output);
```

либо `reduce` укоротить

```
data.reduce((res, elem) => ((res[elem.key] = elem.value),res), {})
```

Comment: а можно чуть поподробнее про конструкцию (res[x] = y, res)

Comment: @Zhihar операторы разделяются запятой. Если мы несколько операторов куда то присваиваем/возвращаем, то вернет последний.